# How to remove a directory which is not empty?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I've been trying to erase (remove) a directory from one of my internal HDD and the system tells me that "The directory can not be removed because it is not an empty directory."

The issue is that the directory IS empty!

At least, I can not to see any inside it with Thunar file manager or from the Terminal with root privileges.

The directory where the directory I want to delete is, has this output to `ls-la`:

```
total 28

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 ene 15 10:01 .

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20480 ene 15 10:01 ..

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 ene 15 10:01 matrimonio de fiesta sara y luis hernan
```

And, the directory I want to delete, has this output:

```
total 8

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 ene 15 10:01 .

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 ene 15 10:01 ..
```

A similar case with another directory which has 3 files and, each time I was trying to remove them, the system tells me: "Files not found."

I was trying with `sudo rm -r -f` and... Nothing!

The same history each time I used it.
What's wrong here?

Is there another, more powerful, command to remove directories and/or files?

Comment: Are there any hidden files in there? Those start with a `.` and are not shown in most GUI file managers by default

Comment: There is no any kind of files in this directory. I have the "Show hidden files" ON in thunar, and at the terminal session, with root privileges, nothing is diplayed.

Comment: The directory might have the immutable bit set. See http://binblog.info/2011/01/30/make-directory-immutable-on-linux/

Answer (score 2):

You can remove **empty** directories with `rmdir <directory>` and **non-empty** directories with `rm -r <directory>`.

---

What causes you trouble, may be the following:
Consider this directory content:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── empty
├── non-empty
│   └── file.txt
└── non-empty-with-hidden-file
    └── .file.txt
```

We have an epty directory, on containing a file and one containing a hidden file. Now run `rmdir *`:

```
$ rmdir *
rmdir: failed to remove `non-empty': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove `non-empty-with-hidden-file': Directory not empty
$ tree -a
.
├── non-empty
│   └── file.txt
└── non-empty-with-hidden-file
    └── .file.txt
```

As you can see, `empty` was removed and the other two caused error messages. Now you can run `rm -r`:

```
$ rm -r non-empty
$ tree -a
.
└── non-empty-with-hidden-file
    └── .file.txt
```

Your `file not found` error is probably not caused by `rm`, but by a typo in your filename or your directory path. You can avoid this by using the autocomplete function (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) instead of typing by hand.

Comment: I did all the instructions you wrote and... Nothing!!! The system doesn't show me any file on the directory but it can not to remove it!!! It is a very rare behaviour, because I can erase any other directory with the commands you wrote!!! This HDD is a NTFS partition; all the directories and files  come from a Windows system. Could it be some part of the reason? ???

Comment: When I use "dir -a", the system shows me a "." (one single dot) and ".."(two dots). If Linux works the same as Windows on this point, those dots are just references to the parents directories. Or... Am I wrong? ???

Comment: About "File not found" issue, it is so rare: when I ask the system a "dir -a" the system shows the files:  "bt_Main_button2.bmp"  "bt-Main_Manual.bmp" and "bt_Manual_Product2.bmp" BUT... When I ask it "sudo rm" and use the [Tab] key, I can only see the "bt_Ma" part of the names!!! What's wrong here? ???

Comment: Okay, I think I can help you to track down your problem. Please edit your question and include the output of the following steps: `cd` to the directory that contains the directory you want to delete; run `ls -la` and `ls -la <name of the dir you want to delete>; Then run `rm <some file in the dir>` and `rm-r <the dir to delete>`.  Btw, as long as your working inside your home directory, you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: I added the information you asked from me. When I use rm or rm -r it doesn't work (system always says the same error mesage).

Comment: your issue may be caused by spaces in the directory name. Please run the following command: `sudo rmdir "matrimonio de fiesta sara y luis hernan"` (notice the `"` around the name). Does this work? If yes, I can add an explanation to my answer

Comment: No. I tried it a lot of times and it didn't work.

Comment: what happens with `rm -rf *`? Normally, this should remove all files and directories in the directory you are currently in.

Comment: rm -rf didn't work for me with this directory. I've tried with others directories and that command works! I created a "/Temp/test" directory and I put some text files on it, and rm -rf removed it as we'd expected! But... in this specific directory... Nothing! Originally, the "infamous" directory had a lot of pictures from a wedding. I uploaded all those pictures to facebook and I made a copy of them into an external HDD, then I erased them from the directory and  I tried to remove it, But... Here, we are!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34406/discussion-between-wayne-yux-and-juan).

Answer (score 0):

Wayne's answer is correct, but if an error occurs you can add the '-f' switch to `rm`, "forcing" the removal:

`sudo rm -rf "/path/to/the/directory"`